# How to inject mock object?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, googlemock

I am trying to do a unit test to test the DoLogin method:

```
CLoginActivity::CLoginActivity()
{
    m_pTask = new Task();
}

void CLoginActivity::DoLogin()
{
    m_pTask.execute();
}
```

where the Task is another class that I need to mock.

```
class MockTask : public Task
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(Execute, void());

};
```

To inject the `MockTask task` object, I must change my construction:

```
CLoginActivity::CLoginActivity(Task& task)
{
    m_pTask = task;
}
```

or write a set function:

```
CLoginActivity::SetTask(Task& task)
{
    m_pTask = task;
}
```

Is there other method to inject instead those two methods? And I use gmock in my unit test project.

Answer (score 4):

Injecting via constructor is the best - keep this design.

But there are few others ways for people that like to complicate simple things.

1) Make your CLoginActivity class template:

```
template <class TaskImpl>
class CLoginActivityTemplate
{
      CLoginActivityTemplate() { m_pTask = new TaskImpl(); }
};

using CLoginActivity = CLoginActivityTemplate<Task>;
```

In your tests, test this instantion:

```
using CLoginActivityTestable = CLoginActivityTemplate<TaskMock>;
```

However it is not always so easy - because it is often hard to get access to this mock to set expentantions on it. But you might define TestMockWrapper class
to ensure access to mock task is easy:

```
class TestMockWrapper : public TestMock
{
public:
     static TestMock* lastCreated;
     TestMockWrapper()  { lastCreated = this; }
}; 
using CLoginActivityTestable = CLoginActivityTemplate<TaskMockWrapper>;
```

2) Inject factory object to your constructor:

```
CLoginActivity::CLoginActivity(ITaskFactory& taskFactory)
{
    m_pTask = taskFactory.create();
}
```

You need to mock this factory class to ensure mock-factory creates mock-object. Maybe it does not look promissing - but this is just intro to next point.

3) Have special factory function implemented in other file:

> CLoginActivity.cpp

```
#include "TaskCreate.hpp"

CLoginActivity::CLoginActivity()
{
    m_pTask = taskCreate();
}
```

> TaskCreate.cpp

```
// your "real" function here
ITask* createTask() { return new Task(); }
```

Having such design- create UT test for your CLoginActivity with using only selected files from your projects - simple speaking - replace TaskCreate.cpp with TaskcreateStub.cpp in your UT project:

1. CloginActivity.cpp
2. TaskMock.cpp (if exists)
3. TaskCreateStub.cpp

TaskCreateStub.cpp should return task-mock - not real task. You need also access to this returned mock-object - so you can set expectations on it.

> TaskCreateStub.cpp

```
// your "real" function here
static TaskMock* taskMockForCreateStub = nullptr;
ITask* createTask() { return taskMockForCreateStub ; }
void setTaskMockForCreateTaskStub(TaskMock* taskMock) { taskMockForCreateStub = taskMock; }
```

I strongly discourage you from using such linker-level mocking. Use it only for testing legacy code where you cannot redesign it and this might be the only way for using mock...